# Level sets of the heat kernel

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For convex bounded domains the level sets of the green's function are also convex (Ahlfors conformal mapping book).

**Q** Are there any such results for the level sets of the heat kernel?

Any references will be appreciated.

**Attempt**

1)What if we consider the mollified green's function eg. $K(x,y,t):=\int H(x,w,t)G(w,u)H(u,y,t)dwdu$? This also solves the heat equation and starts from Green's, so maybe its level sets are easier to study.

2)The Stefan problem seems to be a place where they study level sets of the heat equation.

3)Also, in general I am looking for a book that focuses on level sets approaches in pdes (or at least has some chapters devoted to it).

Suggestions:

1)Stanley Osher, Ronald Fedkiw auth. Level Set Methods and Dynamic Implicit Surfaces

2)Level set method by Sethian etal

But these are both focused on the numerical aspect of that method invented by Sethian and Osher.

Comment: Are you speaking about the heat kernel for the Laplace operator with Dirichlet boundary condition? If yes, the heat kernel is then known to be log-concave for any fixed $t$, which seems to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. any references? How about articles studying the heat kernel level sets?

Comment: This is a partial result in the proof of log-concavity of the ground state, due to Brascamp and Lieb. I suppose there are dozens of review articles or books that discuss this topic. The original reference is Theorem 6.1 (with $\omega = 0$) in DOI:10.1016/0022-1236(76)90004-5, link: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123676900045